# How to select values for parameters in SSRS based on a previous parameter's selection?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, expression

I have a SSRS report that I am creating that has 4 dataset parameters:

- @PullBy
- @Employee
- @FromDate
- @ToDate

All Data Sources and Datasets have been associated with the report and the basic functionality of the report has been setup and tested.

How the parameters work is the @PullBy has 5 options:

1. Employee
2. Supervisor
3. Manager
4. VP
5. Admin

When 1-4 is selected you get a dynamic list generated for the next parameter @Employee.

The user then can (multi) select names from the second list and then set the To and From Dates to generate the report.

This is all working.  I have been tasked to add the Admin option to the first parameter and its function when selected is to do the following:

- Select All the Employees for the second paramter
- Autofill the To and From Dates based on the current month

Is it possible to associate an Expression in SSRS for that parameter value  that will then populate the desired selections in the parameters that follow?

I have searched for an answer to this and maybe it is how I am phrasing the question but I have found no answers thus far.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Edit the Parameter dataset for the dates and Employees. If employees is a multi select then that's ok. If not you need to add functionality to the procs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase to search for would be "SSRS cascading parameters". Yes, it's possible to reference previous parameters in the datasets for subsequent parameter values. If you run into a specific issue once you've tried it, post a new question with as many details as possible and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think my problem was that I was attacking the issue from the wrong angle.  I have this working now by adding the parameters to my second data set with more sql queries to populate correctly. The only change to SSRS was using the Default Values for my parameters.